# CircleCI & Cakephp - Cannot connect to database for phpunit tests

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, circleci, circleci-2.0

I've started to configure a CircleCI integration of my project. I've created the config file using the 2.0 standard. I've got it running smoothly, deploying and everything is working, except the phpunit tests that I've created. When I run the phpunit command, it returns an error (I believe he cannot connect to the database).

```
Unable to insert fixtures for "App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest" test case. SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [***/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php, line 356]
```

Here's my test database config:

```
 'test' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
//            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'common_resources_test',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        ],
```

Here's my circleCI code:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: *removed*
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login
    environment:
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
      DEBUG: true
    docker:
    - image: circleci/php:7.1-apache
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Install Maria DB
        command:  sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1 mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1
    - run:
        name: Initializing Mysql
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: 'sudo service mysql status || sudo service mysql restart; '
    - run:
        name: Set password
        command: sudo mysql -u root -e "USE mysql; UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    - run:
        name: Check settings
        command: sudo mysql -u root -proot -e "USE mysql; SELECT host FROM user WHERE user = 'root';grant all privileges on *.* to root@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES; SELECT host FROM user WHERE user = 'root';SELECT @@port;SELECT @@hostname;"
    - run:
        name: Restarting Mysql
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: 'sudo service mysql status || sudo service mysql restart; '
    - run:
        name: Create Mysql database and show current databases
        command: sudo mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database common_resources_test;SHOW DATABASES"
    - run:
        name: Install required Libraries for PHP-GD
        command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
    - run:
        name: Install PHP Extensions (PHP-GD && PDO-MYSQL)
        command: sudo docker-php-ext-install gd && sudo docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
    - run:
        name: Install Other required Libraries for PHP & Activating PHP-GD and PDO-MYSQL
        command: sudo docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv  && sudo docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && sudo docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd && sudo docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
    - run:
        name: Create folder for Circle Artifacts and Circle Test Reports
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
    - run:
        name: Download Composer
        command:  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - run:
        name: Running Composer Install
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: composer install --no-interaction;
    - run:
        name: Download Yarn
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
    - run:
        name: Install Yarn
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: sudo yarn install
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-
        - v1-dep-pre-production-
        - v1-dep-
    - save_cache:
        key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
        paths:
        - vendor/bundle
        - ~/virtualenvs
        - ~/.m2
        - ~/.ivy2
        - ~/.bundle
        - ~/.go_workspace
        - ~/.gradle
        - ~/.cache/bower
        - ~/.composer/cache
        - ~/.yarn-cache
    - run:
        name: Creating folder for PHPUnit Tests
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/phpunit
    - run:
        name: Running PHPUnit Tests
        working_directory: *removed*
        command: ./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration ./phpunit.xml.dist --log-junit $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/phpunit/junit.xml
    - store_test_results:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
  deployment:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:2.7-jessie
    steps:
      - run:
        name: Install awsebcli
        command: sudo pip install awsebcli
      - run:
        name: Deploy to S3
        command: eb deploy --profile default
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - deployment:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: pre-production
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded a way to fix this problem. Basicly mysql root was not allowed to login using password. Had to set it up. Here's my app.php config:

```
    'test_common_resources' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'unix_socket' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
        'database' => 'common_resources_test',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
    ]
```

And here's my circleci config:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: **removed**
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login
    environment:
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
      DEBUG: true
    docker:
    - image: circleci/php:7.1-node-browsers
    steps:
    - run:
        name: Install Maria DB
        command:  sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1 mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1
    - run:
        name: Initializing Mysql
        command: 'sudo service mysql status || sudo service mysql restart; '
    - run:
        name: Set password
        command: sudo mysql -u root -e "USE mysql; UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    - run:
        name: Check settings
        command: sudo mysql -u root -proot -e "USE mysql; UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root'; SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';grant all privileges on *.* to root@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES; SELECT host FROM user WHERE user = 'root';SELECT @@port;SELECT @@hostname;"
    - run:
        name: Restarting Mysql
        command: 'sudo service mysql status || sudo service mysql restart; '
    - run:
        name: Create Mysql database and show current databases
        command: sudo mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database common_resources_test;SHOW DATABASES"
    - run:
        name: Install required Libraries for PHP-GD
        command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
    - run:
        name: Install PHP Extensions (PHP-GD && PDO-MYSQL)
        command: sudo docker-php-ext-install gd && sudo docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
    - run:
        name: Install Other required Libraries for PHP & Activating PHP-GD and PDO-MYSQL
        command: sudo docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv  && sudo docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && sudo docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd && sudo docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
    - run:
        name: Create folder for Circle Artifacts and Circle Test Reports
        command: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
    - run:
        name: Download Composer
        command:  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - run:
        name: Download Yarn
        command: curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
    - run:
        name: Install Yarn
        command: sudo yarn install
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-
        - v1-dep-pre-production-
        - v1-dep-
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Running Composer Install
        command: composer install --no-interaction;
    - save_cache:
        key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
        paths:
        - vendor/bundle
        - ~/virtualenvs
        - ~/.m2
        - ~/.ivy2
        - ~/.bundle
        - ~/.go_workspace
        - ~/.gradle
        - ~/.cache/bower
        - ~/.composer/cache
        - ~/.yarn-cache
    - run:
        name: Creating folder for PHPUnit Tests
        command: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/phpunit
    - run:
        name: Checking Mysql Status
        command: 'sudo service mysql status'
    - run:
        name: Running PHPUnit Tests
        command: ./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration ./phpunit.xml.dist --log-junit $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/phpunit/junit.xml
    - store_test_results:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
  deployment:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:2.7-jessie
    steps:
      - run:
        name: Install awsebcli
        command: sudo pip install awsebcli
      - run:
        name: Deploy to S3
        command: eb deploy --profile default
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - deployment:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: pre-production
```

Answer (score 2):

I would handle the database the way it is in your config. You can use a second container for the database. Then set the DB creds with environment variables.

The config lines would look something like this:

```
- image: circleci/mariadb:10.1
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "common_resources_test"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
```

Comment: that requires 2 containers, which is a paid service right? I was trying to avoid that by now

Comment: Yes and no. Technically it's two containers but CircleCI only counts the build/execution container when it comes to pricing. Without paying, on a private project, you'll only be able to run one job at a time. With my example, this would still be one job.